# What is the general term for cruft left over after a build?

Tags: terminology

When I run some commands, like certain scripts or Makefiles, a number of files and folders are generated along the way to the final output. (For the moment, let's not go into whether or not the script should tidy up after itself. Sometimes this might be a good idea, sometimes not.) What term describes these files?

(I know what I mean when I say "cruft", but I don't think this is *necessarily* clear, and it could come off as colloquial, which is not what I'm aiming for.)

Answer (score 1):

A common term seems to be "intermediate files"; maybe you could say "intermediate build artefacts" if they are not necessarily just files.

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl refers to them as `Artifacts` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would just refer to them as `~TempFiles` generated by your scripts.

Comment: A bit unwieldy to say with that tilde in there.